# Kubernetes manual setup vs Cloud which one is more viable for a small project

Tags: kubernetes

I am getting into CI/CD and Microservices. I want to try Kubernetes for a project that I am starting. I spent the last two weeks learning about those topics. But I don't have the knowledge to make the decision. I would like to know if for a small project is better to setup Kubernetes in my server or pay a Cloud service. What difficulties I would have to setup Kubernetes manually? My impression is that setting up a Kubernetes by hand is more like toward setting up an email server, is much more viable to pay to have a email domain than set up an email server manually.

I would like only to have kubernetes to get my services up automatically and other basic things.

Comment: It depends on your needs, I'd personally avoid Clouds for small projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an **on-prem** set up and you can expose your cluster you can go with that creating the **K8s** cluster and managing it.

Else are you planning to set up manually on cloud **VMs**? instead better to use managed one from **Digital Ocean** or **Oracle OKE** which may cost around **$20-30** months if a small project.

Now you have the option to use **Kubespray**, and **Kubeadm** to setup the manual cluster and manage it so would be pretty easy to do it but again setting on **VMs** & managing it too much of work, instead go with the provider who gives free control plane and has only pay for **Worker** **Nodes**.

You can also go for the **Serverless containers**, **Cloud RUN** from **GCP** & **ECS** from **AWS** worry about your container **workload** and pay for resources actually your container using with option to **scaling**.

Comment: Good, it opened my mind a little. Pay for cheat (but yet good) kubernetes service like Digital Ocean seems to be viable for a small project. Glad my question wasn't closed. Those types questions really help us when learning a new technology. It's a pity that Stackverflow community commonly  prevents them.

Comment: Definitely you are right, check one DO service and hetzner etc really affordable for small project. Haha before it gets closed written answer.  you are right SO prevent but sometimes those suggestion and discussion opens new door.